# Search function is Not filtering back to original data

Tags: flutter, list, dart, search, todo

[image]

if we search  for any text in the search bar …we get filtered search results... but the issue is that all other To-dos are gone ..

[image]

I cant get back to all   other Todos ..

search function code

```
  List<Todos> todList =[];
searchTodo(String enterdText) {
    final search = todList.where((txt) {
      final inputtext = txt.todoText.toLowerCase();
      final input = enterdText.toLowerCase();
      return inputtext.contains(input);
    }).toList();
    setState(() => {todList = search});
  }
```

search bar

```
TextField(
              onChanged: searchTodo,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Search',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
                  //  enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  iconColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your list to a different variable and once the search ends replace with the saved list.

Answer (score 0):

```
Something like this... little bit confuse on list size if not replace with length

List<Todos> todList =[];
List<Todos> tmpList =[];
searchTodo(String enterdText){
If(tmpList.size<todList.size){

tmpList=todList;
}
if(enterdText.trim().isEmpty()){
final search=tmpList;


}else{
final search = todList.where((txt) {
  final inputtext = txt.todoText.toLowerCase();
  final input = enterdText.toLowerCase();
  return inputtext.contains(input);
}).toList();}
setState(() => {
If(tmpList.size<todList.size){

tmpList=todList;
}

todList = search});
}
```